# What is the difference between coinbase address and normal address?

Tags: blockchain, addresses, coinbase

i am unable to find the difference between these two addresses. Do coinbase address also change after each transaction?

Answer (score 0):

They're just normal addresses. I'm not sure what you're referring to with "also change" as addresses don't really change.

The term "coinbase" typically refers to mining: coinbase address is the address where minted coins are sent. But, as I said, it's a regular address to which you should have the private key.

Comment: Oh.. I thought about coinbase exchnage. lol

Comment: Yeah it can be a bit confusing at first.